# Quitting emacs takes 10 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, freeze

Closing emacs 23 in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 takes very long. I have recursively bisected my .emacs file (as per advice from [Drew](https://superuser.com/users/250462/drew) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/600011/exiting-from-emacs-is-very-slow-how-to-troubleshoot)) and located the following piece as the offending bit:

```
;;auto-complete
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
(define-key ac-completing-map "\t" 'ac-complete) ;; change return key with tab to ac
(define-key ac-completing-map [tab] 'ac-complete) 
(define-key ac-completing-map [return] nil)       

(require 'auto-complete-latex)
(setq ac-l-dict-directory "~/.emacs.d/ac-l-dict/")
;;(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'foo-mode)
;;(add-hook 'foo-mode-hook 'ac-l-setup)
(require 'ac-math)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'latex-mode)   ; make auto-complete aware of {{{latex-mode}}}
(defun ac-latex-mode-setup ()         ; add ac-sources to default ac-sources
(setq ac-sources
 (append '(ac-source-math-latex ac-source-latex-commands  ac-source-math-unicode)
           ac-sources))
)
;;(require 'auto-complete)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'ac-latex-mode-setup)
;;(ac-flyspell-workaround)        ; workaround if using flyspell
```

`

Any advise resolving this this not-life-threatening but annoying bug very welcome.

** Edit based on @lawlist and @Drew answers: **
Thank you @lawlist and @Drew for your time.
describe-variable shows nothing attached that belongs in my .emacs

```
kill-emacs-hook is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is
(ac-comphist-save bc-bookmarks-save save-place-kill-emacs-hook recentf-save-list)
```

kill-emacs-query-functions returns

```
kill-emacs-query-functions's value is (dictree-save-modified)
```

@Drew: tweeking these hooks is beyond my abilities. Should I comment the elements one by one? How? Thanks again.

Comment: How about starting up Emacs **with** the offending code, and typing `M-x describe-variable RET kill-emacs-hook RET` and see if there is some stuff attached to that hook that gets loaded by the offending code.  Perhaps also check out `kill-emacs-query-functions` to see what is attached to that hook.  Here is a link to the manual that describes the usage of those hooks:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html

Comment: +1 to @lawlist's suggestion. Then try removing functions from those two hooks, one at a time, to see which of them is/are the culprit(s). (And perhaps you can pare down the above code a bit more - is all of it needed for you to see the slowdown?) Once you know which code run when Emacs quits is the problem, if it is not clear what to do about it then please post another question here or update this one with that info.

Comment: Before exiting Emacs, try typing:  `M-x eval-expression RET (remove-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save) RET`

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to reflect advice by @lawlist.

Comment: Evaluation of the expression @lawlist recommends returned the bottom of what follows the arrow. Quiting emacs gets fast right after evaluation. Slowness returns with next emacs session.  --> Source file `/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/dictionaries-common/ispell.el' newer than byte-compiled file
ispell.el is already loaded
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
(bc-bookmarks-save save-place-kill-emacs-hook recentf-save-list)

Comment: If Emacs quits expeditiously after evaluating `(remove-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save)`, then BINGO!  All you need to do is find `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save)` in your source code files and comment it out.  It's probably in a file called `auto-complete.el`.  If you have an `auto-complete.elc` go ahead and delete it.  Once everything is working to your satisfaction, you can byte compile a new one using `M-x byte-compile . . .`.  As to your ispell, you've likely modified it somehow.  You can delete the ispell.elc and byte-compile a new one.

Comment: Thanks @lawlist, I seem to be very close to a solution. I have attempted commenting out (add-hook ...) in auto-complete.el. An error occurs while loading `/home/eric/.emacs':

"End of file during parsing: /home/eric/.emacs.d/auto-complete.el".

The part in source code I modified reads: 
(defun ac-comphist-init ()
  (ac-comphist-load)
**;;**  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save)) ;; this makes quitting emacs sloooow

Comment: You probably commented out **more than** just `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save)`.  The most common scenario is that there were more than one closing parentheses at the end and they were commented out also.  If there was anything **after** on the same line (e.g., more than one closing parentheses), then you need to move that other stuff to a new line. For example, `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save))` contains an extra closing parens -- you need to move that extra closing parens to a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to @lawlist, thank you for your time and knowledge!

If Emacs quits expeditiously after evaluating `(remove-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save)`, then BINGO! All you need to do is find `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save)` in your source code files and comment it out. It's probably in a file called `auto-complete.el`. If you have an `auto-complete.elc` go ahead and delete it. Once everything is working to your satisfaction, you can byte compile a new one using M-x byte-compile.

Comment: The function `ac-comphist-save` is responsible for the delay you experience when exiting Emacs.  That function is attached to the `kill-emacs-hook`, which gets triggered when exiting Emacs.  By commenting out `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'ac-comphist-save)`, you prevent the function `ac-comphist-save` from being attached to the `kill-emacs-hook`.  If you now run `M-x describe-variable RET kill-emacs-hook RET`, you should see that `ac-comphist-save` is no longer there.  If the library is still being maintained, you may wish to submit a bug report to the maintainer at some point in the future.